# How to fetch database values between two dates

Tags: java, mysql

```
SELECT absentdt,period FROM stu_attendancemaster 
WHERE classid=70 AND absentdt BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-19'
```

how can i use this query in a java program by passing `from date` and `to date` in a function.

Comment: have you looked at joda-time?

Comment: this question doesn't make too much sense. please edit and make clearer what you need help with.

Comment: how i can pass it in a java method where date ranges from two specified dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is
`Method body`

```
public void callDatabase(String date1, String date2){   
    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select absentdt, period from stu_attendancemaster where classid=70 AND absentdt BETWEEN '"+date1+"' AND '"+date2+"' ");
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();   
    while(rs.next())
    {
        //get data here
    }
}
```

`Method call`

```
String d1,d2;      //initialize
callDatabase(d1,d2);
```

Comment: hope u got ur answer.

Comment: don't forget to mark it as answer if u got ur solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename","root","");  

        PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select absentdt, period from stu_attendancemaster where classid=70 AND absentdt BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-19'");
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();   

        while(rs.next())
        {
            //get data here
        }
```

Comment: k if i dont know the dates it can be entered manually in the run time

Comment: you can set dates by receiving them from user, or using your code. anyway you want.

Comment: can u say the query for me

Comment: '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-19' this two dates can be changed and how i can use in a method